# Tracking file system changes in Windows and Mac

Tags: java, windows, macos, ntfs, hfs+

I have an file system based application written in Java both on Windows and Mac OS.

My requirement is to track the changes made to files/folders under a directory. Operations to track are normal file level operations like CRUD ones. 
when my application runs i can run a watch service from java nio and can track the changes (though detecting rename is still a problem in watch service ).

My problem comes when i have to detect changes when the application is not running. i have read that the file backup software do it through change journal feature of Windows NTFS.

My questions are as follows

(a) Are change journal apis available in . NET managed code of c# (or even in Java)  or only availalbe through c++ as shown in the examples?
(b) Is change jounrnal or equivalent available in HFS plus (mac os) ? if yes, are there apis available (any language)?
(c ) Is there any better way to track the changes done in file system when the application is not running ?

cheers,

Saurav

Answer (score 1):

Read this:

Keeping an eye in the NTFS Change Journal

- Part 1 - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742450.aspx
- Part 2 - http://www.microsoft.com/msj/1099/journal2/journal2.aspx